# Synology CloudSync - change Dropbox password

Tags: synology

I have recently changed my Dropbox password and now my Synology CloudSync doesn't work....i can't find where can i change the Dropbox password inside Synology NAS so i could get my NAS to sync with my Dropbox account.

Comment: So i have found out that it is not possible to change the Dropbox Password because it is not saved anywhere on synology....only way to do this is to unlink the Dropbox sync and make it again on the same folder on synology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the connection within the Cloud Sync administration tool, unfortunately there is no other way.  This is a real problem for non-administrators when changing their password with the Cloud provider, but have to then work through the Synology administrator to update their password.  Hope Synology comes up with a way to make this easier.